# C# Dialog keeps pop up when click yes in Form_FormClosing

Tags: c#, winforms, events

Adding an event in my C# winForms the `FormClosing` but the dialog keeps pop-up after adding the code `Close()`

```
 private void AdminPanel_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = (MessageBox.Show(this,
                                "Are you sure you want to close the Application?",
                                "Exit",
                                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question));
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //dialog keeps poping up when i try to close the form
            Close();
        }
        else {
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: OK, so this feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Is your real problem "**why does closing the form not make my application process stop running?**"?

Comment: Is the form the application's main form? Are there threads or other things that keep the application from closing?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve] (including how the form is invoked) so we can repro the issue at our end.

Comment: I've tried both answers, also I  add `Environment.Exit(0);` in `formClosed` as @Olivier Rogier said. And properly works well. That fixed the problem

Comment: `Environment.Exit` is certainly a valid option - but in 95% of cases its use is not optimal since it means you have made a mistake somewhere else. If you share a [mcve] we can confirm that to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to add a call to `Close` method inside `FormClosing` because you are already in the form close call pattern of Application.

You need to write:

```
private void AdminPanel_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  var result = MessageBox.Show(this,
                               "Are you sure you want to close the Application?",
                               "Exit",
                               MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) );
  if ( result != DialogResult.Yes )
  {
    e.Cancel = true;
  }
}
```

- If `DialogResult.Yes` then it does nothing to `e.Cancel` and the form is closed and the `FormClosed` event is called.
- If `e.Cancel` is set to `true` then the `Close` call is cancelled by the Application manager and `FormClosed` is not called.

If you add a call to `Close` in `FormClosing` you will get a stack overflow : the box is shown and shown and shown and shown and shown and so on without end as long as you click on `Yes`, unless you click on `No`...

If you want to force the application ending you can use in the `FormClosed` event:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

But perhaps you have something somewhere that prevents the close.

Do you have code in `FormClosed` ? Does it throw an exception ? Else you need to catch it because it stops the close.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the `Close();` call? You're already in a `Closing` event handler – unless you cancel the close, it's going to happen anyway.

Comment: Yes it will close but the application is still runing.